# Nominatim failes with "Illegal query string"

Tags: docker, nominatim

I'm currently installing Nominatim using the Docker image that can be found at https://github.com/bringnow/docker-nominatim . However, when I send a query I get the following error:

> Bad Request
>
> Nominatim has encountered an error with your request.
>
> Details: Illegal query string (not an UTF-8 string): paderborn

When I have a look at the console, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  relation "query_log" does not exist at character 13
STATEMENT:  insert into query_log values ('2018-05-23 15:25:03.9961','paderborn','172.18.0.1')
ERROR:  relation "new_query_log" does not exist at character 13
STATEMENT:  insert into new_query_log (type,starttime,query,ipaddress,useragent,language,format) values ('search','2018-05-23 15:25:03.9961','q=paderborn&polygon=1&viewbox=','172.18.0.1','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0','short_name:de,short_name:en-US,short_name:en,name:de,name:en-US,name:en,place_name:de,place_name:en-US,place_name:en,official_name:de,official_name:en-US,official_name:en,short_name,name,place_name,official_name,ref,type','')
ERROR:  function make_standard_name(unknown) does not exist at character 8
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
STATEMENT:  select make_standard_name('paderborn') as string
```

I already found an answer that proposes the following solution:

```
./utils/setup.php --create-functions --enable-diff-updates
```

However, this results in an error:

```
Functions
CREATE FUNCTION
ERROR:  could not access file "/app/module/nominatim.so": No such file or directory
```

When I have a look at the file system, the file nominatim.so exists. So, this error is confusing.

Does anyone know a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake: We have two docker images, one for **nominatim** and one for **postgis**. The file /app/module/nominatim.so is created inside the nominatim image but also needed within the postgis image. The solution is to create a volume that allows to share the file.

Within docker-compose.yaml add the following lines to the nominatim service:

```
volumes:
- ./volumes/module:/mnt/module
```

and the following lines within postgis service:

```
volumes:
- ./volumes/module:/app/module
```

Further extend the entrypoint.sh:

```
log_info "==> Copy nominatim.so"
cp /app/module/nominatim.so /mnt/module/nominatim.so
```

Note that you have to rebuild the nominatim Docker image.